# What is the "substance" of things hoped for?

Tags: greek, hebrews, faith, layers-of-meaning, definition

> Now faith is **the substance** of things hoped for, the evidence of
> things not seen. (Hebrews 11:1, KJV)
>
> ἕστιν δὲ πίστις ἐλπιζομένων **ὑπόστασις** πραγμάτων ἔλεγχος οὐ
> βλεπομένων (TR)

What is this "substance" (ὑπόστασις) of things hoped for?  If something is "hoped for," it seems it would be something entirely unmaterialized, unrealized, and intangible.  How could it have any "substance"?

Comment: υποστασις Translated ‘substance’ narrows the definition in English to the exclusion of its true sense. It is the substrata, the foundation, the thing that something else rests upon, it conveys confidence, or the real deal. “Faith is what hope sits on” as opposed to how you read it in English “Faith is an element...”

Answer (score 2):

The word *substance* (Latin ''substantia'' from''sub'' - under + ''stance'' - stand) is the Latin counterpart of the Greek *hupostasis* ( ''hupo'' - under + ''stasis'' - stand). Thus, substance is a literal translation of υποστασις in Hebrews 1:3. The word ''substance'' has different meanings ( *ground, foundation, basis, support, confidence, nature, etc.*) and context helps in determining its exact meaning in a text.

> [Hebrews 11:1 Literal Standard Version (LSV)](https://biblehub.com/lsv/hebrews/11.htm):
>
> ''Now **faith is [the] substance of things hoped for**, [the] proof of
> matters not being seen''.

### Faith being substance is what makes our future hope a present reality.

> Now faith is the substance (so A.V., with marginal readings, "or
> **ground**, or, **confidence**") of things hoped for, the evidence of things
> not seen. On the senses in which the word ὑπόστασις (translated
> "substance") may be used, see under Hebrews 1:2. As to the sense
> intended here, views differ. There are three possible ones, expressed
> in the text and margin of the A.V., substance, ground, and confidence.
> The first is **understood by the Fathers generally, the idea being
> supposed to be that, inasmuch as things not yet experienced, but only
> hoped for, become real to us by faith, faith is metaphysically their
> substance, as substantiating them to us. So Theophilus: Οὐσίωσις τῶν
> μήπω ὄντων ὑπόστασις τῶν μὴ ὑφεστηκότων: and Chrysostom, who
> illustrates thus: "The resurrection has not yet taken place, but faith
> substantiates (ὑφίστησιν) it in our souls.**" So also Dante, following
> St. Thomas Aquinas, in a striking passage quoted by Delitzsch
> ('Paradise,' 24:70-75) (Pulpit Commentary)

Faith is the ''substance, support'' [ὑπόστασις] of our hope, that it (i.e. our hope) for will surely happen because God will do it (Hebrews 11:1). Faith is the ''substance, metaphysical nature'' [ὑπόστασις] of what we hope for which means that what we hope for doesn't exist yet, but that it truly exists in us, that is, in our minds which fully trusts in God that God will do what he says, that he will fullfill his promises. This is the kind of faith God wants us to have. v. 2 says: ''Indeed, by faith our ancestors received approval.'' This is the faith that God require us in order for him to work in us as seen in the long list of his peoples from "all time" (from beginning of the Jewish people up to these last days from v. 4 to v. 39).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the Latin meaning of "substance" is closest to the Greek ὑπόστασις, but the English word has a somewhat different meaning from the Latin.

BDAG might be helpful here.  That lexicon gives this meaning and comment:

> (1) **the essential or basic structure/nature of an entity,
> *substantial nature, essence, actual being, reality*** ... (b) of things: among the meanings that can be authenticated for Heb 11:1 a
> strong claim can be made for ***realization*** ... in faith hoped for
> become realized, or things hoped for take on (see 3, and 4
> below) reality ...

Among the modern versions, the most popular appears to be:

> Now faith is the **assurance** of things hoped for ...

This is consistent with the material in BDAG.

Comment: I don't understand the expression you quoted from the commentary: "in faith hoped for become realized, or things hoped for take on".  Is that even grammatically correct?  I don't grasp what it's trying to say.

Comment: That is "lexicon speak" - very terse for something like: "in faith, things hoped for become realized; or, things hoped for take on reality".  Note the first two words of the lexical entry, "of things".

Answer (score 0):

Elisha's servant had an interesting experience in 2 Kings 6:

> 15 When the servant of the man of God got up and went out early the next morning, an army with horses and chariots had surrounded the city. “Oh no, my lord! What shall we do?” the servant asked.

The servant saw the physical army of the king of Aram. Their mission was to capture Elisha.

> 16 “Don’t be afraid,” the prophet answered. “Those who are with us are more than those who are with them.”

Elisha saw something that his servant did not see. A greater army was protecting them. They were invisible to the servant but visible to Elisha. In any case, they were real.

> 17 And Elisha prayed, “Open his eyes, Lord, so that he may see.” Then the Lord opened the servant’s eyes, and he looked and saw the hills full of horses and chariots of fire all around Elisha.

Now, the servant saw the reality.

> 18 As the enemy came down toward him, Elisha prayed to the Lord, “Strike this army with blindness.” So he struck them with blindness, as Elisha had asked.

There were no conventional physical fights between the two armies. The job of the heavenly army was to strike the Aramean soldiers with blindness.
This was a miracle. An act from the heavenly realm caused a result in the physical realm.

Now, let's head for the NT, Hebrews 11:

> 1 Now faith is the substance of things hoped for, the evidence of things not seen.

Faith is this physically invisible substance that supports the things hoped for.
We can't see it physically. Nevertheless, it is there and it is real. It may even have mass :)

This is similar to the concept of [dark matter](https://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/StarChild/universe_level2/darkmatter.html):

> Dark matter is composed of particles that do not absorb, reflect, or emit light, so they cannot be detected by observing electromagnetic radiation. Dark matter is material that cannot be seen directly. We know that dark matter exists because of the effect it has on objects that we can observe directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hope comes from faith.

But hope and faith are in vain if you do not have charity, or if you are not humble and meek.

It is not wrong to think of a spiritual thing as a substance. All spirit is matter. There is no such thing as immaterial matter.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).